# Weird magento import issue

Tags: magento, csv

I've got an weird Magento issue while importing products with an CSV file.
First im gonna check the data and Magento is happy with it

```
Checked rows: 603, checked entities: 61, invalid rows: 0, total errors: 0
```

And he only import the '61 checked entities'. I have no idea what im supposed to do to solve this problem.
So do someone of you guys recognize this problem? Please can someone help out?

Im using Magento version 1.7.0.2

Already thanks

Comment: Example csv row of a failed product would be helpful.

Comment: Thats the problem. The import doesn't fail. He just import 61 (random) products and not the full 603.

Comment: How are you sure it is random? Have you opened the csv with a program that could of malformed it, //glares at Excel.. Update us with things your have tried.

Comment: I've first imported the 'product options and colors' and everything went fine. I've double checked them

    Checked rows: 120, checked entities: 120, invalid rows: 0, total errors: 0

And its the same script... I edit the script/CSV in Komodo Edit and its not malformed. I dont get it where the 'data check' is checking on...

Comment: How many Sku Rows do you have in csv? Propably 61?

Comment: SKU is an required field. So the data check would see that as an error if a line doesn't have an SKU.|

So all lines have an unique SKU

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I used delimiter double quote (") , and separator coma (,) on my csv.
In my case, I was importing desccription in html.  And sometimes, I used the csv delimiter " in the content of my descriptions.
That's how some rows were skipped during import, but valid during the test.